# Angular 6: Failed to compile: Can't resolve 'stream' in ./node_modules/hash-base

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular6

I updated three Angular 5 apps to Angular 6 but the last one gives me troubles.
Every time i try to compile (serve/build, jit/aot, dev/prod) i get this errror:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/hash-base/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '[...]/node_modules/hash-base'
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

hash-base seems to be a webpack dependency:

```
@eagle5/editor-app@0.2.6
└─┬ @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.6.1
  └─┬ webpack@4.6.0
    └─┬ node-libs-browser@2.1.0
      └─┬ crypto-browserify@3.12.0
        └─┬ create-hash@1.2.0
          ├─┬ md5.js@1.3.4
          │ └── hash-base@3.0.4 
          └─┬ ripemd160@2.0.2
            └── hash-base@3.0.4  deduped
```

Some specialties of this app are that i have a framework in ./src beside the app folder and i install a git repository as npm package and import some typescript definitions like so in my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@nettrek/*": [
        "./@nettrek/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*",
    "./node_modules/@eagle5/player-core/dto/**/*"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "preserveWhitespaces": false
  }
}
```

I tried to install [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream) stream npm package but this version doesn't has the stream.Transform extension that hash-base uses.

I tried node 8.11.1 and 10.1.0

Comment: try `npm -ls`. Do you getting any error like package missing?

Comment: no npm ls gives me no errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found the reason for the error. We used md5.js in one class ourself and forgot to put it in our package.json because it was aleready installed.
Md5.js needs of course the node in browser shims that angular 6 no longer supports.

Comment: How to add md5.js?

Comment: It does appear to have been the md5 package. I switched to this instead https://github.com/cotag/ts-md5

Comment: I also use the [ts-md5](https://github.com/cotag/ts-md5) package. Import it like this `import { Md5 } from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';`

Answer (score 0):

try to add 'stream' to your project

```
npm install stream --save
```

Comment: While this might fix the issue, it might also break something as stream refers to a node.js construct, which is not available in the browser.